# Custom keyword suggestion in IntelliJ

Tags: javascript, c++, intellij-idea

I have a custom Javascript API implemented in C++ that I want to make work like any other API that IntelliJ can parse, i.e. I want keyword suggestions and highlighting.  Being implemented in C++, the javascript API is made up of glue code that generates the API in runtime. So there is no Javascript code for IntelliJ to parse like for a normal API.

Does anyone know if its possible to manually define the keyword suggestion and relations between classes and methods in IntelliJ ? I cant find anything in the doc, maybe I've missed something in the plugin documentation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to create a static script that would generate the stubs of your JS API as source files, and link those files to IntelliJ IDEA as a JS library.

It is also possible to write a plugin that would extend the JS plugin to provide all the definitions dynamically, but this would be significantly harder and, as you correctly note, there's no documentation for that.